# How to host asp.net core aplication on godaddy windows hosting server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web-deployment, web-hosting, shared

I have an application running on asp.net core mvc architecture. I need to deploy and run the application on godaddy Shared hosting windows based server. All my files are already uploaded on godaddy server but the application is still not running. when ever i try to access the application using godaddy domain it says Future home of something quite cool.

Any suggestions or solutions would be much appritiated

---

ted

Comment: What version of dotnet core are you using? Godaddy only seems to support up to version 2.0 https://au.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/Does-GoDaddy-s-shared-Windows-hosting-plan-support-ASP-NET-Core/m-p/142380/highlight/true#M867

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate. i m using asp.net core 2.1 version.

Comment: It seems like plesk is supporting the different version of asp.net core https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000442805-ASP-NET-Core-versions-in-Plesk

Comment: Plesk doesn't officially support .net core. So, you must ask your provider to setup .net core for you on the server. If they don't support it, then you must change your provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Godaddy is currently using Plesk Onyx which only supports dotnet core versions 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0.

Godaddy has not upgraded to the latest version of Plesk so they do not support later versions.

[This post by their community manager confirms the versions](https://au.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/Does-GoDaddy-s-shared-Windows-hosting-plan-support-ASP-NET-Core/m-p/142380/highlight/true#M867)

Note that dotnet core version 2.0 is [no longer supported by Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

**Edit: Plesk Windows Hosting now supports the latest .NET versions. See here: [Software versions installed on Hosting accounts](https://in.godaddy.com/help/software-versions-installed-on-linux-hosting-windows-hosting-and-managed-wordpress-accounts-897)**

Comment: So this means i cannot host my application then, can i downgrade the core version or should i migrate to asp.net mvc

Comment: It is up to you to decide what is best for your project. You can find other hosting, downgrade to core v2.0 or switch to dotnet framework 4.x

Comment: @seeratmahajan Is there any error message that you see? Please make sure that they have setup .net core on the server. I also use Plesk control panel here on Asphostportal. Plesk doesn't support .net core officially, so you must ask your provider to setup it for you. Just make sure that .net core has been installed properly on the server.

Comment: I had a .Net 5 application uploaded to the server and I was getting a 500.21 exception. I spoke to one of their agents and they confirmed a maximum of ASP.Net Core 2.0, so I downgraded the application and re-uploaded and it does work. Why the hell they're on such a low version, I have no idea!

Comment: .NET core 7.0 is supported in 2023 here is proof : https://in.godaddy.com/help/software-versions-installed-on-linux-hosting-windows-hosting-and-managed-wordpress-accounts-897